# How to create new div dynamically, change it, move it, modify it in every way possible, in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to create new divs as the page loads. These divs will appear as an ordered group which changes depending upon external data from a JSON file. I will need to do this with a for loop because there are over 100 divs needed.

So, I need to be able to change each created div in regards to height, width, top/left and so on. Yet, `document.getElementById("created_div").style.whatever` does nothing, I can't even see a single new div appear. I've set the new divs height/width to 500px, background to "red", and so on, but no new divs are definitely appearing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Share the code you use to create divs

Comment: $("#box0").append('<div id="created_div"></div>');

Comment: If you're doing this in a loop, does that mean you're attempting to create 100 divs with the same identifier?

Comment: look in browser console...any errors? Even though ID should not be repeated...shouldn't stop it being inserted if selector exists and no errors thrown.Errors are first critical check

Comment: besides creating them, do you insert them in the DOM ?

Comment: Not even trying a loop yet so I'm just using a single ID. No browser errors. How to insert into DOM?

Comment: your code doesn't create any div. I suggest you use the javascript framework jQuery, and do as Erik Nelson suggested (the new divs will be created inside the element with the id "box0").

Comment: depending on your json data, you may also want to try another javascript library than jQuery, called d3js

Answer (score 446, accepted):

- [Creation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement) `var div = document.createElement('div');`
- [Addition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/node.appendChild) `document.body.appendChild(div);`
- [Style manipulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.style)

  - Positioning `div.style.left = '32px';` `div.style.top = '-16px';`
  - [Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.className) `div.className = 'ui-modal';`
- Modification

  - [ID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.id) `div.id = 'test';`
  - [contents (using HTML)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML) `div.innerHTML = '<span class="msg">Hello world.</span>';`
  - [contents (using text)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/node.textContent) `div.textContent = 'Hello world.';`
- [Removal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/node.removeChild) `div.parentNode.removeChild(div);`
- Accessing

  - [by ID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) `div = document.getElementById('test');`
  - [by tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName) `array = document.getElementsByTagName('div');`
  - [by class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) `array = document.getElementsByClassName('ui-modal');`
  - [by CSS selector (single)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.querySelector) `div = document.querySelector('div #test .ui-modal');`
  - [by CSS selector (multi)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.querySelectorAll) `array = document.querySelectorAll('div');`
- Relations (text nodes included)

  - [children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/node.childNodes) `node = div.childNodes[i];`
  - [sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/node.nextSibling) `node = div.nextSibling;`
- Relations (HTML elements only)

  - [children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.children) `element = div.children[i];`
  - [sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.nextElementSibling) `element = div.nextElementSibling;`

This covers the basics of DOM manipulation. Remember, element addition to the body or a body-contained node is required for the newly created node to be visible within the document.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/)? Vanilla javascript can be tough. Try using this:

```
$('.container-element').add('<div>Insert Div Content</div>');
```

`.container-element` is a JQuery selector that marks the element with the class "container-element" (presumably the parent element in which you want to insert your divs). Then the `add()` function inserts HTML into the container-element.

Comment: Well, I got it. I had to set padding to greater than 0. Even though its height and width are set to 64 each. Bleh. Is there any way for a child div to act like a normal div? The goal is to get each div to act like a link. Trying to create a dynamic list for a game website ;/

Comment: I don't agree with this, innerHTML (what jquery uses for that) is *NOT* standard, and the price of not following the standard may lead to missbehaviour. Also, for me, it do not make any sense to add a plan html string into a DOM tree rather than to add node elements.

Comment: Considering that the entire DOM tree starts out life as plain old HTML, and that innerHTML is just that - the HTML that an element has in it, having a problem with either is on par with saying you shouldn't use the DOM because it polluted the plain old HTML.