# Creating dynamic div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
 <script>
    function selecteditems()
    {

    var i=1;
    var val="";
    while(i<=53)
    {

        if(document.getElementById('timedrpact'+i)!="")
        {
            val+=document.getElementById('timedrpact'+i).value;
            document.getElementById('showselecteditems').innerHTML=val;
            }
        i++;
        }

    }
    </script>
```

How to create a new div and add contents to it?In the above case i lost previous content due to innerHTML.I want new div each time for dynamically attach an image and the above variable val to it.
[image: The desired and current output demonstrated here]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to create new div dynamically, change it, move it, modify it in every way possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14094697/javascript-how-to-create-new-div-dynamically-change-it-move-it-modify-it-in)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n4AUW/)

```
<div id="output" class="out">

</div>

window.onload=function(){
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    var i=1;
    var val="";
    while(i<=3)
    {

        if(!document.getElementById('timedrpact'+i))
        {
            var ele = document.createElement("div");
            ele.setAttribute("id","timedrpact"+i);
            ele.setAttribute("class","inner");
            ele.innerHTML="hi "+i;
            output.appendChild(ele);

        }
        i++;


    }
};
```

Comment: hi 1
hi 1
hi 3
hi 1
hi 3
hi 4
Hi i got ouput like this.First time i got hi 1,Next time i got hi1,hi3.etc.Previous value got appended

Comment: @Anoop you want to remove previous one ?

Answer (score 5):

Look at `document.createElement()` and `element.appendChild()`.

```
var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
newdiv.innerHTML = val;
document.getElementById("showselecteditems").appendChild(newdiv);
```

---

Because you will likely encounter this in the near future: You can remove any `element` with this code:

```
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement):

```
function selecteditems() {
  var container = document.getElementById('showselecteditems');
  for (var i=1;i<=53;i++) {
    var fld = document.getElementById('timedrpact'+i);
    if (fld) {
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(fld.value));
      container.appendChild(div);
    }
  }
}
```

Full version using cloneNode (faster) and eventBubbling

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/kAbz4/)

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
var lnk = document.createElement("a");
var img = document.createElement("img")
img.className="remove";
img.src = "https://uperform.sc.gov/ucontent/e14c3ba6e4e34d5e95953e6d16c30352_en-US/wi/xhtml/static/noteicon_7.png";
lnk.appendChild(img);
div.appendChild(lnk);
function getInputs() {
  var container = document.getElementById('showselecteditems');
  for (var i=1;i<=5;i++) {
    var fld = document.getElementById('timedrpact'+i);
    if (fld) {
      var newDiv = div.cloneNode(true);
      newDiv.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].appendChild(document.createTextNode(fld.value));
      container.appendChild(newDiv);
    }
  }
}    
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById('showselecteditems').onclick = function(e) {
    e=e||event; 
    var target = e.target||e.srcElement; 
    // target is the element that has been clicked
    if (target && target.className=='remove') {
      parentDiv = target.parentNode.parentNode;
      parentDiv.parentNode.removeChild(parentDiv);
      return false; // stop event from bubbling elsewhere
    }
  }    
  getInputs();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for dynamic create div:

```
  DivId =  document.createElement('div');
  DivId.innerHtml ="text"
```