# How to get alerts message instead of showing it as message box ? webbrowser control

Tags: c#, javascript, html

I am looking for a way to get the string of JavaScript alerts messages instead of showing it as message box,now, I am using a code to block alerts form a web page, this is the code (c#):

```
HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
HtmlElement scriptEl = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
string alertBlocker = "window.alert = function () { }";
element.text = alertBlocker;
head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
```

I have this in web browser control navigated event.

I am very new to JavaScript that's why :)

Thank you very much.

Comment: Get the message in what way? What do you want to do with it instead?

Comment: i want to get the text of alert's message instead of showing it as message box,for example, i want to show it in a label, not in message box.

Answer (score 1):

> string alertBlocker = "window.alert = function (msg)
>   {document.write(msg);}";

there you can write the message to a hidden div/span/etc and then get that hidden div's innerText.

Comment: thank you very much, but as i said above i am so new to HTML, could you please show me how to do that ? :)
or to give me a guide to start with ?

Thanks

Comment: here's a link that might help you in creating a new div element. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19494339/creating-dynamic-div-using-javascript 

and this to make that div invisible and not shown

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456289/how-to-make-a-div-visible-and-invisible-with-javascript

those are using pure javascript. there is also a javascript library called jQuerry that is very usefull for making things easier, but i'm not very familiar with it..